# Generating an additional artifact when crate is used as a dependency

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, dll-injection

I don't know if the title is phrased very well but I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a project consisting of two crates, `main-program` and `patch`, the goal of the program is to capture audio from other processes on the system.

`patch` is a library crate that compiles to a DLL with a detour to hook into the system audio functions and sends the audio data over IPC.

in `main-program` I have some code that does the injection, as well as to receive the data over IPC.

Currently, I just have batch script that calls `cargo build` for each crate, and then copies the DLL and EXE to my output folder.

---

Now, what I want to do, is break out the code that does the injection and the receiving of data, and together with the `patch` crate, I want to create a library, `my-audio-capture-lib` that I can publish for use by others.

The optimal result would be that someone can add `my-audio-capture-lib` to their cargo.toml as a dependency, specify somewhere what filename they want the DLL to have, and then call a function like `my-audio-capture-lib::capture_audio_from_pid` in their code to recieve audio data. And when they build their project they should get their binary, as well as the DLL from my crate.

This however requires that at some point during the build process, `my-audio-capture-lib` produces the necessary DLL for injection. And I don't know how to do that, or if it's even possible to do.

Comment: So `my-audio-capture-lib` would have the DLL artifact built from the `patch` crate, and `my-audio-capture-lib` would inject that DLL at runtime in order to capture audio. Is that correct?

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, that's correct. And I'm trying to figure out how to distribute the DLL from the `patch` crate together with `my-audio-capture-lib`. I suppose I could include it, pre-compiled in the `my-audio-capture-lib` crate. But I would much prefer if it got compiled on the consumer dev's machine when they build their project. Or I don't know if I can provide some build-tool with `my-audio-capture-lib` that can be used to compile the DLL.

Comment: I hope there's a better way, but `build.rs` is highly flexible. You could probably ship both crates together and call into `cargo run` to build the other crate, etc.